# No Image in PictureBox C#

Tags: c#

I have a code with PictureBox but when i want to start my Form, my picture box doesnt have image.

```
public Form1()
{
    PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();

    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\\obrazki\bat2.jpg");
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;

    pictureBox1.Left = 100;
    pictureBox1.Top = 100;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but try first to make `IntializeComponent()` the first line in your code and tell me if that works

Comment: You're not adding the PictureBox to your Form.

Answer (score 1):

Your `PictureBox` does have an image, but it is not visible. You haven't added it to the controls.

```
public Form1()
{
    PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();

    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\\obrazki\bat2.jpg");
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;

    pictureBox1.Left = 100;
    pictureBox1.Top = 100;

    // missing line
    Controls.Add(pictureBox1);

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

There is no point in setting `Visible` to `true`. It is a default value for a `PictureBox`.